# Is there a more maintainable way to initialize structs?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Let's say you have a struct like this:

```cpp
struct Foo {
   int a;
};
```

Currently I am initializing it like this:

```cpp
Foo foo = {1};
```

Now, if I add another member:

```
struct Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

The code still compiles, the compiler considers the initialization is completely fine. But I want the compiler to produce an error when I add new members to the struct. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you need to keep `Foo` an aggregate?

Comment: @NathanOliver Ehhm, sorry, what does aggregate mean? I have been learning c++ for like only 3 days...

Comment: In C++ `struct` and `class` are nearly the same thing. Any reason why you aren't using a constructor? When the signature of the constructor changes the compiler will throw an error like you want for all of the uses that haven't been changed.

Comment: Basically it means a class like what you have.  One that doesn't have any constructors.

Comment: @Romen Yep, I am aware of constructors, but I didn't want to add them. What I wanted is just to add a member and see an error, without a constructor (that you have to also maintain).

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, I wish I could keep my structs simple and declarative. And that's not the case if I add constructor, IMHO

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev, If you don't want constructors then you must use aggregate initialization, which is a language feature that can't really be changed. Some would consider it a *feature* to be able to leave the excluded members zero-initialized.

Comment: @Romen I see. Thanks for clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using [*aggregate initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), whose behaviour is built in to the language and cannot be changed. Aggregate initialization will allow you to leave some members uninitialized. However, you can tell GCC and Clang to issue a warning using [`-Wmissing-field-initializers`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). You can also turn this into an error using `-Werror=missing-field-initializers`.

You can also forbid aggregate initialization within the language itself, by making your class not an aggregate, and instead forcing users to use your declared constructor:

```
struct Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
   Foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
};
```

Now `Foo foo = {1};` will not compile, since aggregate initialization does not apply here, and there are not enough arguments for the constructor.

However, keep in mind that if the constructor you declare fails to initialize all the members, *e.g.*, you wrote something like this by accident:

```
struct Foo {
   int a;
   int b;
   Foo(int a, int b) : a(a) {}
};
```

then again you'll have an issue. But it's possible to make the compiler warn you about this, as well.

Comment: Wow, didn't read till the end, yet, just one quick question, do you know `missing-field-initializers` flag for msvc? Quick-googled with no result.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev no, sorry

Comment: `/Wall /WX` should be a rather picky mode for MSVC. I'm not sure even `int main() {}` would pass :-) [Details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks, I'll try them!

Comment: Oh my. Looks scary: [example @ godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CU76Kf) I think you should start with `/W4 /WX`. That seems to work better: [another example](https://godbolt.org/z/XsNwpW)

Comment: @TedLyngmo ewwww. Reminds me of when I tried to disable MSVC's language extensions (like binding a temporary to a non-const reference). It was bad. Couldn't compile its own internal headers anymore.

Comment: @alterigel I'm not surprised :-) To be fair, MS recommends using `/W4` for new projects, but I wonder who  has use for `/Wall`? Someone not using any standard headers presumably...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Lol, I was going to try them incrementally from W1 to Wall but you've done the work already, thanks for the goldbolt site also! Didn't know